# Form is failing to update mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

So I'm currently working with a form where the admin can select multiple users from the database via a tickbox system, then change the welcome message or general message to a client when they log in:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once("isadmin.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Update Client Message</title>
<link href="loginmodule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
        echo '<ul class="err">';
        foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
            echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
    }
?>
<form id="updateform" name="updateform" method="post" action="updateexec.php">
  <table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th width="200">Select User</th>
      <td>
<?php
require_once('config.php');

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");

        }


$useruploadids = mysql_query("SELECT member_id, firstname, lastname FROM members");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($useruploadids)) {
    $userid = $row['member_id']; 
    $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    $lastname = $row['lastname'];
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="userid_<?php echo $userid ?>" value="y" /><?php echo     $firstname ?><?php echo $lastname ?><br />
<?php } ?>
</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <th>Message For Client </th>
      <td>
      <textarea input name="otherdeets" type="textarea" class="textfield" id="otherdeets" style="width: 356px; height: 176px">
          </textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So this is the form, and it works fine, it calls all users from the database and displays them in tickbox fasion.

I can only assume my issue is in the exec script:

```
<?php 

 echo( "<pre>" );
 print_r( $_POST );
 echo( "</pre>" );

include ("config.php"); 
$tbl_name="members";
    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");

        }

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $update = $_POST['otherdeets']; 
 $id = $_POST['userid'];

 // Cycle through each member and check that it needs to be added to the db
$useruploadids = mysql_query( "SELECT member_id FROM members" );
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($useruploadids))
{
    // Check that the member was sent from the last form
    if( isset( $_POST['userid_'.$row['member_id']] ) &&     $_POST['userid_'.$row['member_id']] == "y" )
    {


// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET otherdeets='$update' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);  
    }
 }

 if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='admin-welcome.php'>Admin Home</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
 ?>
```

When I run the script it simply says:

```
Array
(
    [userid_1] => y
    [otherdeets] => Blah Blah
    [Submit] => Update
)

ERROR
```

Any idea what is wrong? Knowing my luck it would probabaly be a spelling mistake

Thank you

Comment: here use  concatenation of id like 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET otherdeets=' ".$update." ' WHERE id=' ".$id." ' ";
print the query if its coming fine. it its fine then check if you have privileges for update in mysql user.

Comment: Try putting `or die(mysql_error())` after `$result=mysql_query($sql)` to see if there is an error. Also, you shouldn't use [mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) functions since they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: @Ameer no need for that, variables get processed in double quotes!

Comment: add echo $sql; before $result=mysql_query then check the sql syntax. If you can, try in phpmyadmin or directly in mysql bash.

Comment: Also the mysql extension is deprecated, you should switch to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You shuold prepare your variable too... using `mysql_real_escape_string()`. if you still use `mysql_` functions

Comment: Its bad practice to make your db connection inside the page. You should extract that part and move it in a own file.

Answer (score 0):

Hey your query is wrong there should be where condition with appropriate column name i.e. "member_id"

And one more thing 
you are fetching the `$id = $_POST['userid'];` which is an error as there is no value exist with that key
rather you do in the if condition before doing the update query, i.e. 
`$id = $POST['userid'.$row['member_id']];`

Comment: U should not post an answer that is vulnerable to SQL injections. This will teach OP just bad coding...

Comment: I would suggest editing their answer instead of telling them not to even post the answer. It's more constructive.